# Is Google+ SignIn usable as an OpenId?

Tags: php, openid, google-plus

I have a comprehension problem with this Google+ SignIn:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

May I use this as an OpenId for my Homepage with the possibility to set a php session and not just a Javascript token.

Or is this just to get the rights to post or comment on Google+?

Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but you can *not* use the Google+ Sign-in as an OpenId endpoint. It's based on OpenID Connect which is different to OpenId.

You can use Google's OpenID endpoint: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID but you won't have Google+ access.

Or you can use OpenID + OAuth2: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#oauth but you won't have Google+ access.

Or you can server-side OAuth2Login: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login and ask for Google+'s OAuth2 scopes for access to most features of the Google+ platform.

Or you can just use Google+ Sign-in: https://developers.google.com/+/ This is the recommended solution as it provides client libraries for most major languages and you get access to the full functionality of the Google+ platform.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *sure* but I believe you can use Google's OpenID system to request "basic information about your account." That is how I am logged in to Stack Exchange. As for PHP, take the JS trigger and send a GET/POST to the appropriate PHP script.

Comment: but how may get the Data as POST-Data to a Site? Up to now I get the Data I requestet in an JS-Array. Is that possible with that G+-Login, or is it just for Javascript

Comment: @Jokus If you have the data in a JS array, you might want to see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/2329281) for information on how to POST to PHP from JS.